# How to find the difference between joining date and current date of and employee

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I find the difference between the joining date of an employee and the current date, using a select query?

The employee table contains the joining date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(datepart, JoinDate, GETDATE()) AS TimeInService FROM Employee
```

The datepart represents the type of boundary crossed in the calculation.  Minutes, Seconds, Days, etc.  The [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) documentation will help you sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

Difference in days:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( dd , e.JoiningDate, getdate())
FROM employee e
```